# Getting Wrong value when scanning the barcode (1-9101102) gives me (1-91011W2)

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

I am trying to use the barcode scanner to scan a barcode with the tag 1-9101102 but in Notepad on my computer it's showing as 1-91011W2. For some unknown reason instead of second from the last character being 0 it is showing  as a W.

I am not sure why this is happening and looking for advice.

Comment: What bar-code reader do you use? Does it happen with other codes too? Did the issue started already when you first used the reader, or did it work correctly at the beginning? ...

Comment: I am using the symbol bar code reader. Yes, it was working fine before and it only making changes to the second last character changing it from 0 to W.

Comment: Also, the tag may be wrong.  Most phones these days have the capability of reading a barcode, if not built in, there are many apps - you can see what they say.  Or post a picture of the barcode so others can test.